# FLUTTER - Getting this null check error, despite having null safety through out the code

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Getting this null check error, despite having null safety through out the code.
I'm attaching a git repo
https://github.com/HidayatBukhari01/Notes-App.git
can someone please check this code and explain why am i having this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eag2v.png)

On clicking + icon data should have been inserted into notes table, instead it's throwing null safety error!.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check, if the value becomes null, if it does, the above error is evident. Else, you need to put the "?" operator, before the variable or function where the above error occurs, as -

```
type ?<varname> = <Text here>.
```

Even I am new to Flutter. if  you get this error resolved, great, else check out  on other's answers

Answer (score 0):

I went  through your code and here is the mistake you done

```
dbHelper!
```

Here you said that said that dbHelper is not null but the value its getting is null and before calling this check its value in console first,
and use it like this only

```
dbHelper
```

Comment: I changed DBHelper? dbHelper to late DBHelper dbHelper and avoid using bang operator with insert method, still this show the same null error

Comment: Have you called the value of DbHelper in console to check if its really contains any value or not because if you changed it to late and then still getting the same error then it means dbHelper doesn't have any data